# Splashscreen doesn't appear when application starts. PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm working with PhoneGap desktop application and PhoneGap Build to make and compile an Android application.
I want to show a splash screen at the start of the app because i have some loading work to do in the background, once the loading is finished i hide the splash screen and show the content.

I'm using "cordova-plugin-splashscreen v5.0.2" i used this code to show and hide the splash screen:

```
//Show Splash Screen
navigator.splashscreen.show();

//Hide splash Screen after loading has finished
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

this is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>NexusPhoneGap</name>
    <description>
        A blank PhoneGap app.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />

    <platform name="android">
        <splash src="splashScreens/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="splashScreens/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="splashScreens/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="splashScreens/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    </platform>

</widget>
```

I put the splash screens in the a folder called splash "splashScreens" as you see in the config.xml.
The problem is the splash screen isn't appearing. I see a blank screen instead of the splash screen. Any idea how to get the splash screen showing?

Comment: You cannot put the images in a folder you created. You need to put them in `res/screen/android/` and `res/screen/ios` (folders that already exist), respectively. Be sure to run `cordova prepare` after that.

Comment: I created the project with PhoneGap Desktop so i dont have those folders, so i should create them? one second question: what's the purpose of the `cordova prepare` command?

Comment: Then I'm not sure if what I recommended will work. You should look at the documentation for that plugin. In a straight cordova project, running "cordova prepare" copies the images inside those folders and adds them to their respective platforms.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thanks a lot, i probably will see the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for quite some time. I too have an old, non-standard project config and paths. Changing 'density' to 'qualifier' worked.
So change,

```
<splash src="splashScreens/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
```

to

```
<splash src="splashScreens/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
```